# Why FileChannel reading never ends?

Tags: java, nio, filechannel

When I execute following class

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;

public class FileChannelTest {                                                                                                                      
    public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException {                                                                              
        final File file = File.createTempFile("temp", null);                                                                                        
        file.deleteOnExit();                                                                                                                        
        // write some                                                                                                                               
        try(OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {                                                                                     
            output.write(new byte[128]);                                                                                                            
            output.flush();                                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                                                           
        System.out.println("length: " + file.length());                                                                                             
        // read to end                                                                                                                              
        try(FileChannel channel                                                                                                                     
            = FileChannel.open(file.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.READ)) {                                                                           
            final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(128);                                                                                     
            for(int read; (read = channel.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {                                                                                  
                System.out.println("read: " + read);                                                                                                
            }                                                                                                                                       
        }                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                               
}
```

The reading loop never ends.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
$ java FileChannelTest.java
$ java FileChannelTest
length: 128
read: 128
read: 0
read: 0
read: 0
...
...
...
```

[FileChannel.read(ByteBuffer)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#read-java.nio.ByteBuffer-) says,

> Reads a sequence of bytes from this channel into the given buffer.
>   Bytes are read starting at this channel's current file position, and then the file position is updated with the number of bytes actually read. **Otherwise** this method behaves exactly as specified in the `ReadableByteChannel` interface.

What does **Otherwise** mean?

Comment: "Otherwise" here is used to mean "in all other regards", i.e. the only thing they have documented is how it differs from `ReadableByteChannel.read`, not its whole behaviour.

Comment: There are two questions here: (1) why does my code behave like this, which is answered; (2) what does 'otherwise' mean, which is barely credible.

Comment: @EJP I attached the second question about **otherwise** to understand the behaviour of `FileChannel`. I could google for myself if I wanted to know what the word **otherwise** means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read into a ByteBuffer, it can only read as many bytes as is available in the buffer i.e. `byteBuffer.remaining()`  This means once the buffer is full, when you do a read it returns `0`.

I suggest you use either `clear()` if you have consumed all the data read, or `compact()` if you have consumed only a portion of the data read.

```
      for(int read; (read = channel.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {                                                                                  
            System.out.println("read: " + read);    
            buffer.clear(); // so we can read more data                                                                                           
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Peter Lawrey above provides the solution to your infinite loop. In addition to this, to answer your question about what **otherwise** means in the documentation of `FileChannel` class as per my understanding :

From the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#read-java.nio.ByteBuffer-) :

> Reads a sequence of bytes from this channel into the given buffer.
>   Bytes are read starting at this channel's current file position, and
>   then the file position is updated with the number of bytes actually
>   read.

This method will behave exactly like the `ReadableByteChannel.read` method under blocking and non-blocking I/O mode and in terms of thread-safety requirements. The **only additional** operation it performs (read specialization in OOP terminology) is that the `FileChannel.read` implementation will also increment the file position with the number of bytes actually read from the channel.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not correct. It will read bytes into the buffer starting at the current position, bounded by the limit, and adjust the position accordingly.

Comment: @EJP Yep - there was a typo - i used the term  "beginning of buffer" in a loose sense. Edited my answer. Thanks!!

Comment: It doesn't read *from* the buffer. It reads *into* the buffer. And it updates the *buffer* position. You would be much better off quoting the actual Javadoc, rather than continually mangling it into your own, incorrect words.

Comment: Increment the file position *with* the number of bytes read, not 'to'. Why do you keep mangling the text?

Comment: @EJP Please note it is not intentional. I have corrected the statement under question but I think after having quoted the Java doc clearly any additional explanation around that context would be understood by the user. What i have focused on is explaning what the additional operation is and the meaning of the word *otherwise* since there is already an explanation of what the method does in the accepted answer.